# Как запустить такое окно приложения "Android SDK Manager"?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, android-emulator

Когда я скачиваю из интернета программу "Android SDK Manager" то когда я скачиваю у меня появляется папка с такими файлами:
Ни одни из этих файлов не запускаются, кроме sqlite3.exe. Просто появляется командная строка, но какие команды нужно вводить - понятия не имею.
[image: Файлы в архиве при скачивании]

Но как мне запустить **такое окно**? **Брал я его из интернета**[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я просто хочу запустить старые версии Android в этой программе, но само приложение запускать я не знаю как. На Android Studio версии меньше 4.0 не запускаются. **Нужны 3.0 и ниже.**

Comment: хм, у меня 2.3 тоже не запускается. А если старую версию АС установить?

Comment: Когда устанавливаю старую версию, просит удалить новую версию Android Studio

Comment: [Это?](https://androidinsider.ru/smartfony/kak-ustanovit-android-sdk-na-windows-mac-i-linux.html)

Comment: ну и как я написал в удаленном ответе - это окно не для запуска эмулятора, это просто сервис для скачивания сдк и системных образов

Comment: вопрос уже решен и на него не нужно писать ответы, я уже скачал программу "Android SDK and AVD Manager"

Answer (score 0):

[image]

В Android Studio Файл/Settings. Здесь можно выбрать и установить старые версии SDK.